# Brand of Handleset?

Tags: repair, doors

[image]

I need help to identify this handleset. Please do not suggest replacement because the homeowner's association will not allow that. 
I need to replace the thumb piece but cannot order it without knowing the brand. I found one paper sticker for production date of Nov 1984. It is polished brass handleset with single cylinder lock. The latch plate says Kwikset, but believe prior owner replaced it and Kwikset does not recognize.
It needs cleaning which will be tackled when replacing the thumb piece. Problem with it is that the door locks (thumb piece not operable) when slammed but can still be opened with the key at this point. Need to fix ASAP.

Comment: Your best bet is to call a professional locksmith (pick one that's been in business many years) that may have parts on hand and can repair what you have.  I doubt you're going to be able to order specific parts anywhere.

Comment: I will not leave this as an answer because Tyson has already answered most of it, The other part you do not want it as an answer anyway. I can pretty much assure you the HOA knows these things need replacing through the life of the home. For cheap latchsets Kwickset, Schlage, Dexter and the like, 20 to 30 years is about the life expectancy. It is like specifying the brand of paint when the color is the only thing that is important to them. They usually want the latchset replaced with the same color, function and style. It does not have to be THAT particular latch that stays with the door.

Comment: After reading @jack ask the HOA where to get parts.  I suspect you're in a condo or something like where everyone's in the hallway matches.  If it was manufactured in 84 you're not the only unit with parts wearing out.

Comment: Absolutely. Get the HOA's specification for what make and model of doorknob set to use.   If they refuse to spec a doorknob which is purchasable, you're off the hook.

Comment: VTC - How silly. You expect folks to identify the handle set by looking at the guts of the thing.